# What should a YAML template optional step parameter null value be?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

When using a template parameter like this:

```
parameters:
- name: runStep
  type: step
```

It always requires passing a value. I would, however, like to make it optional:

```
parameters:
- name: runStep
  type: step
  default: ???
```

For `stepList` it can be done like so:

```
- name: runSteps
  type: stepList
  default: []
```

But how could it be done for type `step`? I could add a "dummy" default value:

```
default:
  script: echo 123
```

However, how could I compare that value in a condition? I'd like to do something like this:

```
- ${{ if parameters.runStep }}:
  - ${{ parameters.runStep }}
```

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I've clarified the title.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```yaml
step:
- bash: |
    if [ ${{parameters.runstep}} ]; then
       ${{parameters.runstep}}
    fi
```

Comment: This would only work for running shell commands and not Azure Pipelines tasks.

Comment: Ok my bad I misunderstood. So you want to compare the value against something or just return boolean?

Answer (score 0):

> What should a YAML template optional step parameter default value be?

According to the document [Template types & usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameter-data-types):

[image]

So, the default value of YAML template optional step parameter should be **a step**, like:

```
parameters:
- name: myStep
  type: step
  default:
    script: echo my step

steps:
- ${{ if parameters.runStep }}:
  - ${{ parameters.runStep }}
  - script: echo HelloWorld!
```

[image]

Comment: This would always execute because the default value would always be a step, so the condition (`if parameters.runStep`) is pointless.